# Executing batch file breaks when checking if variable has value

Tags: batch-file

To chcek if file is loaded or not, I load its contents using:

```
set /p filevar=file.txt
```

and check if var is empty:

```
if "%filevar%"="" exit
```

When script chceks file with multiple lines, execution of script stops, so i suppose that chcecking fails. Why script fails? How to perform such check properely?

Comment: `set /p filevar=file.txt` does ***not*** load the contents of file.txt into variable `filevar`. It writes the string "file.txt" to the screen and waits for a single line of user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you've got the syntax of your `set /p` command messed up.  As it is, it will prompt the user with the text "file.txt".  I think what you mean is

```
set /p "filevar=" <file.txt
```

You should also use the `/b` switch with `exit` to prevent the console window from closing if your script is run from the command line.

But yeah, as jeb states, to check whether left equals right, either use `==` or `equ`.  Or, as dbenham reminds me, if you're checking for an empty value, you can also use `if not defined`.

```
if "%filevar%"=="" exit /b
if "%filevar%" equ "" exit /b
if not defined filevar exit /b
```

All three statements will have the same result<sup>1</sup>.

In a console window, enter `help if` for more information.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's worth mentioning that, while those three `if` statements have the same result outside of a parenthetical code block, only the third one will work reliably within parentheses (such as in a `for` loop).  The first two would need delayed expansion to work properly if used within the same code block as `%filevar%` is set.

Comment: Or simply check if variable is defined using `if not defined filevar exit /b`