# batch read file without new lines

Tags: batch-file

I've script that reads into variable content of files, but in some cases, files has new lines. Variable has loaded olny firest line. I use:

```
set /p varfile=file.txt
```

Is it possible to read contents of the file with ignored newlines? I cannot find solition wihtin batch commands.

Comment: You have to use a `for` loop to process the contents of your file line-by-line.  Did you [give up on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232125/)?  You left no comments, didn't accept the answer, and are otherwise neglecting it.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee the total size of your file is less than 8191 bytes long, then you cannot do this within a batch file. Batch cannot work with variables larger than 8191 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is probably not what you need, this is what you asked for.  You can capture the entire contents of a file to a single variable (up to 8191 bytes, is it?) by using a `for` loop.  Since `for /f` can read the contents of a file, you can finally eliminate that `set /p` statement you keep misusing.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem // capture a line break to a variable
set BR=^


rem // Leave the two lines above blank.

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("file.txt") do (

    if not defined contents (
        rem // set contents variable to first line of file
        set "contents=%%I"
    ) else (
        rem // append line break + next line to variable
        set "contents=!contents!!BR!%%I"
    )
)

echo(!contents!
```

Now, what are you going to do with this variable now that it contains the entire contents of a text file?

Comment: Only potential problem with this is it will strip empty lines.

Comment: It will also have problems if there are exclamations in input file